# How can I direct trafic to two different subfolders?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a very simple problem I can't seem to fix. I have two subfolders: one for Laravel and the other one for React.

If the user tries to access `example.com/api` or `example.com/admin`, I want his request to go to the Laravel subfolder WITHOUT having `example.com/laravel/api` visible in the URL.

If the user tries any other request, eg. `example.com/profile`, I want his request to go to the React subfolder WITHOUT having `example.com/react/profile` visible in the URL.

I know it's really basic, but I need help to understand this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the root `.htaccess` file try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Internally rewrite /api and /admin to /laravel subdirectory
RewriteRule ^(api|admin)$ laravel/$1 [L]

# Everything else is rewritten to the /react subdirectory
# Except for requests (including rewritten requests) to "/laravel" itself.
RewriteRule !^laravel/ react%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

This does assume that there are additional `.htaccess` files in the `/laravel` and `/react` subdirectories that also contain mod_rewrite directives.

**UPDATE:** If you don't have an `.htaccess` file in the `/react` subdirectory, which also contains mod_rewrite directives, then you'll need to add a condition to the second rule to prevent a rewrite loop (500 error). For example:

```
# Everything else is rewritten to the /react subdirectory
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) react/$1 [L]
```

By checking against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable we ensure that only direct requests (ie. not already rewritten requests) are rewritten to the `/react` subdirectory.

Comment: I got an error 500 when I do that, I will try to change some things. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an additional `.htaccess` file in the `/react` subdirectory containing mod_rewrite directives? As mentioned, these directives assume that you do, otherwise you'll get a 500 error due to a rewrite loop. These directives can be modified to account for this if required. Do you have any other directives in this `.htaccess` file?

Comment: (I assume you must already have a `.htaccess` file in the `/react` subdirectory, otherwise, how are the react URLs routed?) Note that for any 500 error you should check your server's error log for the details of this error.

Comment: I've updated my answer.